# Get exact diff in an Angular $watch function when watched value is an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

Controller:

```
 $scope.$watch('userData', function(val, oldVal){
     if(!val){
          return; 
      } 

      console.log(filtersService.lastChange(val, oldVal))
}, true);
```

Service:

```
    .service('filtersService', function() {
        var _lastChange = {};
        var api = {

            lastChange: function(val, oldVal, nested){
                var __filters = ['filters', 'weights'];
                if(angular.equals(val, oldVal)){
                    return;
                }

                for(var i in val){
                    if(!nested){
                        if(__filters.indexOf(i) == -1){
                            continue;
                        }
                        _lastChange = {};
                    }

                    if(typeof val[i] == 'object'){
                        if(!angular.equals(val[i], oldVal[i])){
                            if(!nested){
                                _lastChange[i] = api.lastChange(val[i], oldVal[i], true);

                            }
                            else{
                                _lastChange[i] = angular.copy(val[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else if(val[i] != oldVal[i]){
                        var __obj = {}
                        __obj[i] = val[i];
                        return __obj;
                    }
                }
                return _lastChange;
            }
        };

        return api;
    });
```

I have a $watcher that watches an object that represents form data that can be changed by the user.
Naturally, oldVal differs from val only by one element, usually primitive.
the form data consists of 3-levels nesting, so to determine the diff I use recursion, In order to allow the user to reset all of the filters except of his last change (handy feature for a scenario where there are no results).

example of the data:

```
val = {
    age: 50,
    filters: {
        brands: "a_naturals",
        flavors: "Caramel",
        ingredients: null
    },
    gender: "male",
    weight: 50
}
oldVal = {
    age: 50,
    filters: {
        brands: "naturals",
        flavors: "Caramel",
        ingredients: "sugar"
    },
    gender: "male",
    weight: 50
}
```

I would expect the returned value to be {filters: {ingredients: null}}, but it does not work properly, and the recursion stop condition is not reached for some reason.
It doesn't work for 3-levels nesting either.

It does work when one of the primitive values, or simple nested values are changed to non-null values (typeof null === 'object' issue?).

Comment: Is your function called at all? If not, add a third argument of `true` to your `$watch` or use `$watchCollection`. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: it's called, the problem is in the diff calculation